# What's the most effective non-stealth hand-to-hand combat strategy for a fort captain?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

In AC3, I have a little trouble beating the captain of the fort in close range non-stealth combat, who is usually able to counter a counter with a damaging punch to the face.  This means that I can either take the hit or counter it and take a smaller hit (or maybe dodge, haven't tried that yet).

I think a kick works somewhat, but if I remember correctly the captain usually counters a killing blow from the knife or the tomahawk  (haven't tried sword yet).

This has forced me to use stealth strategies to take out the captain.  Which is annoying because sometimes I try to take the whole fort on at once [Commando-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commando_%28film%29) and the captain spoils the fun.

**What is the best combo for fighting the fort captain in open combat?**

**What is the best melee weapon class (short blade, axe, sword, musket, etc) for honorable combat with the captain?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fort captains aren't all that special.  They're just another archetype in the game's different enemies.

It's not a new one either, they are all* the **Jager** archetype and are vulnerable to disarms.  But you cannot initiate the attack, *they* must attack you and you must do a counter disarm.

You can disarm them by pressing **Off Hand** -> **Foot** as they attack you (have the red triangle over them).  That's **B** -> **A** on an Xbox 360 Controller, **Circle** -> **X** on a PS3 Controller  or <kbd>E</kbd> -> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> on the PC keyboard.  Once disarmed, you should have no trouble finishing them off.

There is also a challenge to disarm 10 Jagers and kill them with their own weapon.

<sub><sup>*They are all the same archetype as far as I can tell.</sup></sub>

Comment: I played through the game using the Tomahawk always but it really shouldn't matter which melee weapon you use.

Comment: Disarming is a good plan. Also don't forget to use your 'gadgets' whilst fighting. If you have a pistol you can attack and press your gadget button to shoot them. I tend to use the rope dart to knock them over and just stab them whilst they are down. Clean, simple and works 100% every time.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAsk4sg_FLI

Answer (score 0):

I've had no issues as such with fighting the fort captain, as even I go fighting with all guns blazing. I use the disarm maneuver and then beat the hell out of the captain. Even the Counter + Gun move works well.

Answer (score 0):

I try to beat the captain as honourably as possible. I found there is only 1 way to do that. (No guns, no rope darts, and no stabbing them when they are down or disarmed) Start without a weapon, wait for him to hit you, block+disarm, take his sword, IMMEDIATELY switch to fists, attempt to punch him BEFORE he picks up another weapon. He will block your punches. BEFORE you send your 4th punch, hit X (disarm key) ONCE, NOT TWICE. This will pop him in the nose, disorienting him. Then punch him, and continue to alternate between disarm and punch until he is knocked out. Whether you kill him or not is up to you, but I would spare him.